# MouseOver info box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Here is what I want to do . To make an information box apper when I roll the mouse over an image/text.

This is an example.

**Before :**

[image]

**After :**

[image]

This happens when I go with the mouse over the little icon , but when I've done the printscreen the cursor did not appear . Any suggestion ? Please make it easy . I accept any language .

Comment: Don't understand. You want that when you mouse over the image it should show the text??

Comment: title attribute of HTML element is what you want.

Comment: I think he has done that already and just ownders why the cursor is not appearing at the printscreen :)

Comment: I know why it doesn't apper , I didn't know about the attribute . Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `title` attribute, as explained in this page :
[W3.org](http://w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-title)

Comment: Please offer official links!

Comment: @AndreasFurster I'll do if I know what it is =p, can you explain/link to something explaining ?